# How to set a JButton to be undecorated and remove the MouseListener

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton

I made a JButton and I am trying to remove the mouse events that is the "borders and colors" that comes with it by default. I tried the following:

```
 setUndecorated(true);
```

But it wasn't the right code to do that.

Is there a way to remove the MouseListener that the JButton brings and set the JButton to how you want it to be decorated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to set a JButton to be undecorated...

If you want to play with buttons decoration then take a look to [AbstractButton](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html) API (class which [JButton](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html) extends from). Particularly these methods:

- [setContentAreaFilled(boolean flag)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setContentAreaFilled%28boolean%29): Sets the `contentAreaFilled` property. If `true` the button will paint the content area. If you wish to have a transparent button, such as an icon only button, for example, then you should set this to `false`.
- [setBorderPainted(boolean flag)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setBorderPainted%28boolean%29): Sets the `borderPainted` property. If true and the button has a border, the border is painted.
- [setRolloverEnabled(boolean flag)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setRolloverEnabled%28boolean%29):
  Sets the `rolloverEnabled` property, which must be true for rollover
  effects to occur.
- [JComponent.setBorder(null)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setBorder%28javax.swing.border.Border%29): since some look and feels might not support the `borderPainted` property, in which case they ignore this, you might want to set the buttons border to `null` instead.

> ...and remove the MouseListener

Don't understand what do you mean but I suspect you want to get rid of the animation that takes place when the button is pressed or perhaps roll-over efects. If this is the case then playing with methods mentioned above should be enough.

Comment: Do you mean `setFocusable(false)` to "remove" the border (if any) when the button is focused? If so I'll add it to my answer :) But doing all those changes you'll get a clickable `JLabel` :P @mKorbel

Comment: and remove the MouseListener is setFocusable for me